# Tentative formula for the derivative of the logarithm of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

I have the following problem:

given the function:

$$f(N,B_j,C_j)=\ln\sqrt{1+\sum_{j=1}^N\dfrac{B_jk^2}{(k-C_j\omega)(k+C_j\omega)}}$$

with $k$ constant and $k\in\mathbb{R}$, $B_j\in\mathbb{R},C_j\in\mathbb{R}$
is there a general formula for:

$$F(N,B_j,C_j)=\dfrac{d}{d\omega}f(N,B_j,C_j)$$
for $N$ a finite integer number? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Tentative formula" implies you have an as yet undisclosed conjecture for $F$.

Comment: There is a clear way to manually differentiate this. Are you asking if there is a *nice* closed form?

Comment: @FShrike:yes I'm asking that